# Python reading csv problem : extra whitespace

Tags: python, csv

When I tried to parse a csv which was exported by MS SQL 2005 express edition's query, the string python gives me is totally unexpected. For example if the line in the csv file is :"
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd", then when python parsed it as string, it becomes :" a a a a , b b b , c c c, d d d d" something like that.....What happens???
I tried to remove the space in the code but don't work.

```
import os
import random


f1 = open('a.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('dec_sql.txt', 'w')
text = 'abc'

while(text  != ''):

    text = f1.readline()
    if(text==''):
        break

    splited = text.split(',')
    for i in range (0, 32):
        splited[i] = splited[i].replace(' ', '')

    sql = 'insert into dbo.INBOUND_RATED_DEC2010 values ('
    sql += '\'' + splited[0] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[1] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[2] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[3] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[4] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[5] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[6] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[7] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[8] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[9] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[10] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[11] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[12] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[13] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[14] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[15] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[16] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[17] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[18] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[19] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[20] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[21] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[22] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[23] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[24] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[25] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[26] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[27] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[28] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[29] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[30] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[31] + '\', '
    sql += '\'' + splited[32] + '\' '

    sql += ')'

    print sql
    f2.write(sql+'\n')


f2.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the input file? It would make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: problem solved. The file is a unicode file. I used Ultraedit to convert it to a ascii file, then python works again. Thanks all.

Comment: If you figure out which characters are being rejected you can add to the ENCODING_REGEX_REPLACEMENT_LIST in my code example and skip the Ultraedit step.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It may help to use Python's built in CSV reader. Looks like an issue with unicode, a problem that frustrated me a lot.

```
import tkFileDialog
import csv

ENCODING_REGEX_REPLACEMENT_LIST = [(re.compile('\xe2\x80\x99'), "'"),
                                   (re.compile('\xe2\x80\x94'), "--"),
                                   (re.compile('\xe2\x80\x9c'), '"'),
                                   (re.compile('\xe2\x80\x9d'), '"'),
                                   (re.compile('\xe2\x80\xa6'), '...')]

def correct_encoding(csv_row):
    for key in csv_row.keys():
        # if there is a value for the current key
        if csv_row[key]:
            try:
                csv_row[key] = unicode(csv_row[key], errors='strict')
            except ValueError:
                # we have a bad encoding, try iterating through all the known
                # bad encodings in the ENCODING_REGEX_REPLACEMENT and replace
                # everything and then try again
                for (regex, replacement) in ENCODING_REGEX_REPLACEMENT_LIST:
                    csv_row[key] = regex.sub(replacement,csv_row[key])
                print(csv_row)
                csv_row[key] = unicode(csv_row[key])
        # if there is NOT a value for the current key
        else:
            csv_row[key] = unicode('')
    return csv_row

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(open(filename, "rb"), dialect='excel') # assuming similar dialect
for csv_row in csv_reader:
    csv_row = correct_encoding(csv_row)
    # your application logic here
```

Comment: Wow, which brave person decremented me and didn't leave an explanation.

Comment: It was I.  Your code is a well written kludge that guesses at encoding and sweeps errors under the rug.  The correct approach, as referenced in srgerg's answer, is to know your encoding and deal with it.  The OP was poorly served in accepting your answer.

Comment: The code I posted explains how to remedy the issue. While it isn't perfect, it is a concrete solution that can be modified and used in the real world (not an academic answer that you want). And if you have an issue with which answer was accepted, then you should decrement the question and not the answer.

Comment: -1 just for using a regex to change UTF-8 encode bytes to ASCII.

Comment: I agree the regex is a poor use since it's replacing static bytes. The code is adapted from a different example I have. Despite this, the regex code can easily be removed by someone who encounters this problem in the future.

Comment: @pokstad: It was -1 for replacing UTF-8-encoded bytes with ASCII, no matter whether you did it with re.sub or str.replace or a subprocess running awk -- the sin is doing ANYTHING with UTF-8-encoded bytes other than decoding them.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like the output of the MS SQL 2005 query is a unicode file. The python [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) cannot handle unicode files, but there is some [sample code](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples) in the documentation for the csv module describing how to work around the problem.

Alternately, some text editors allow you to save a file with a different encoding. For example, I opened the results of a MS SQL 2005 query in Notepad++ and it told me the file was UCS-2 encoded and I was able to convert it to UTF-8 from the Encoding menu.

Comment: It's what Microsoft call a "unicode" file. It's actually UTF-16(LE).

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file in notepad and use the replace all function to replace `' '` with `''`

Answer (score -1):

Your file is most likely encoded with a 2byte character encoding - most likely utf-16 (but it culd be some other encoding.

To get the CSV proper reading it, you'd open it with a codec so that it is decoded as its read - doing that you have Unicode objects (not string objects) inside your python program.

So, instead of opening the file with

```
my_file = open ("data.dat", "rt")
```

Use:
import codecs

```
my_file = codecs.open("data.dat", "rt", "utf-16")
```

And then feed this to the CSV module, with:

import csv
reader = csv.reader(my_file)
first_line = False
for line in reader:
   if first_line: #skips header line
       first_line = True
       continue
   #assemble sql query and issue it

Another thing is that your "query" being constructed into 32 lines of repetitive code is a nice thing to do when programing. Even in languages that lack rich string processing facilities, there are better ways to do it, but in Python, you can  simply do:

```
sql = 'insert into dbo.INBOUND_RATED_DEC2010 values (%s);' % ", ".join("'%s'" % value for value in splited )
```

Instead of those 33 lines assembling your query. (I am telling it to insert a string inside
the parentheses on the first string. After the `%`operator, the string ", " is used with the "join" method so that it is used to paste together all elements on the sequence passed as a parameter to join. This sequence is made of a string, containing a value enclosed inside single quotes for each value in your splited array.

Comment: PS. there is not something like an "unicode file" like other answers imply. There are several diferent encodings, each of whcih is able to express a different subset of the unicode character table.

Comment: -1 You can't feed it unicode or UTF-16; you need to recode it from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and feed that to the csv reader. See the examples in the (2.x) csv module manual.

Comment: ... and UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, and GB18030 can represent *ALL* `2**21` (approx) Unicode code points.